# how to customize hover tooltip

Tags: javascript, plotly, plotly.js

I have a plot that has multiple curves as shown in the attached.

```
var data = [
    {
        type: 'scatter',
        mode: 'lines+markers',
        name: 'Main.app.folder.section31.floor17.room8.box56.label6.nameA',
        x: [1,2,3,4,5],
        y: [2.02825,1.63728,6.83839,4.8485,4.73463],
        showlegend: false
    },
    {
        x: [1,2,3,4,5],
        y: [3.02825,2.63728,4.83839,3.8485,1.73463],
        name: 'Main.app.folder.section31.floor17.room8.box56.label6.different',
        showlegend: false
    },
    {
        type: 'scatter',
        mode: 'lines+markers',
        name: 'Main.app.folder.section31.floor17.room8.box56.label6.unknown',
        x: [1,2,3,4,5],
        y: [5.02825,4.63728,3.83839,2.8485,0.73463],
        hovertemplate: '(%{x},%{y})',
        showlegend: false
    },

]; 

var layout = {
    title: "Set hover text with hovertemplate",
};

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
```

https://codepen.io/mmakrzem/pen/mdOpWLd

Each of the curves have a really long name so I'd like to customize the hovertemplate so that it shows (x,y) ...

For for my example I'd expect to see something like `...bel6.nameA` or `...different` or `...l6.unknown`.  Whereas right now I'm getting `Main.app.fol...` for all the plots so I can't differentiate between them.  I also tried setting the hovertemplate to just (x,y) but then the whole name is shown and that is just ridiculously long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each trace, you can add the string you want to display using the `customdata` argument and setting it equal to an array of strings the same length as the x and y arrays you pass to each trace (for example, `customdata: Array(5).fill('...nameA')`).

Then you can modify the `hovertemplate` to include `%{customdata}` and hide the long trace name completely by adding the string `<extra></extra>`.

Your hovertemplate will look like this: `'%{x},%{y} %{customdata}<extra></extra>'`

My codepen is [here](https://codepen.io/merillium/pen/NWaWXMR) if you want to take a look.

```
var data = [
    {
        type: 'scatter',
        mode: 'lines+markers',
        name: 'Main.app.folder.section31.floor17.room8.box56.label6.nameA',
        x: [1,2,3,4,5],
        y: [2.02825,1.63728,6.83839,4.8485,4.73463],
        customdata:Array(5).fill('...nameA'),
        hovertemplate: '%{x},%{y} %{customdata}<extra></extra>',
        showlegend: false
    },
    {
        x: [1,2,3,4,5],
        y: [3.02825,2.63728,4.83839,3.8485,1.73463],
        name: 'Main.app.folder.section31.floor17.room8.box56.label6.different',
        customdata:Array(5).fill('...different'),
        hovertemplate: '%{x},%{y} %{customdata}<extra></extra>',
        showlegend: false
    },
  {
        type: 'scatter',
        mode: 'lines+markers',
        name: 'Main.app.folder.section31.floor17.room8.box56.label6.unknown',
        x: [1,2,3,4,5],
        y: [5.02825,4.63728,3.83839,2.8485,0.73463],
        customdata:Array(5).fill('...unknown'),
        hovertemplate: '%{x},%{y} %{customdata}<extra></extra>',
        showlegend: false
    },
  
];

var layout = {
    title: "Set hover text with hovertemplate",
};

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  I don't like the ideas of inserting an array into customdata since I have a lot of data points, but I did figure out that I can create my own property and just reference it so I ended up doing this:

    {
        type: 'scatter',
        mode: 'lines+markers',
        name: 'Main.app.folder.section31.floor17.room8.box56.label6.unknown',
        shortname: '...unknown',
        x: [1,2,3,4,5],
        y: [5.02825,4.63728,3.83839,2.8485,0.73463],
        hovertemplate: '(%{x},%{y})<extra>%{data.shortname}</extra>',
        showlegend: false
    },

Comment: That's a good solution - I wasn't aware that you can create your own property in plotly.js